# What's the difference between pls_integer and binary_integer?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, associative-array

I've inherited some code which is going to be the base for some additional work. Looking at the stored procs, I see quite a lot of associative-arrays.

Some of these are indexed by binary_integers, some by pls_integers. Are there any differences between the two?

I had a look at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#LNPLS319), but apart from this line:

> The PL/SQL data types `PLS_INTEGER` and `BINARY_INTEGER` are identical. For simplicity, this document uses PLS_INTEGER to mean both `PLS_INTEGER` and `BINARY_INTEGER`.

I couldn't find any difference between the two. So what's the difference? Are both around for historical/compatibility reasons?

I'm using Oracle 10gR2

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Historical reasons. They [used to be different before 10g](http://www.oracleplsqlprogramming.com/oppnews_200512.html):

> On 8i and 9i, PLS_INTEGER was noticeably faster than BINARY_INTEGER.

---

> When it comes to declaring and manipulating integers, Oracle offers lots of options, including:
>
> INTEGER - defined in the STANDARD package as a subtype of NUMBER, this datatype is implemented in a completely platform-independent fashion, which means that anything you do with NUMBER or INTEGER variables should work the same regardless of the hardware on which the database is installed.
>
> BINARY_INTEGER - defined in the STANDARD package as a subtype of INTEGER. Variables declared as BINARY_INTEGER can be assigned values between -2<sup>31</sup>+1 .. 2<sup>31</sup>-1, aka -2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647. Prior to Oracle9i Database Release 2, BINARY_INTEGER was the only indexing datatype allowed for associative arrays (aka, index-by tables), as in:

```
  TYPE my_array_t IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) 
  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER
```

> PLS_INTEGER - defined in the STANDARD package as a subtype of BINARY_INTEGER. Variables declared as PLS_INTEGER can be assigned values between -2<sup>31</sup>+1 .. 2<sup>31</sup>-1, aka -2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647. PLS_INTEGER operations use machine arithmetic, so they are generally faster than NUMBER and INTEGER operations. Also, prior to Oracle Database 10g, they are faster than BINARY_INTEGER. In Oracle Database 10g, however, BINARY_INTEGER and PLS_INTEGER are now identical and can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Here is the 9i docs, which mention the difference, but without going into much detail: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/03_types.htm#10531 Anyway, it's obsolete now.

Comment: But look at the link below :
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/plsql/documentation/new-plsql-features-in-action-doc-129893.pdf

Binary_Integer implementation is based on Hash like data structure so should it be faster for searching
and PLS_INTEGER for ordering as they are implemented on B*-Trees

Answer (score 9):

`binary_integer` and `pls_integer` both are same. Both are PL/SQL datatypes with range -2,147,648,467 to 2,147,648,467.

Compared to `integer` and `binary_integer` `pls_integer` very fast in excution. Because `pls_intger` operates on machine arithmetic and `binary_integer` operes on library arithmetic.

`pls_integer` comes from oracle10g.

`binary_integer` allows indexing integer for assocative arrays prior to oracle9i.

Clear example:

```
SET TIMING ON

declare
  num   integer := 0;
  incr  integer := 1;
  limit integer := 100000000;
begin
  while num < limit loop
    num := num + incr;
  end loop;
end;
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:20.23
ex:2
declare
  num   binary_integer := 0;
  incr  binary_integer := 1;
  limit binary_integer := 100000000;
begin
  while num < limit loop
    num := num + incr;
  end loop;
end;
/ 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:05.81
ex:3
declare
  num   pls_integer := 0;
  incr  pls_integer := 1;
  limit pls_integer := 100000000;
begin
  while num < limit loop
    num := num + incr;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Range is actually -2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647.

Answer (score 4):

Another difference between pls_integer and binary_integer is that when calculations involving a pls_integer overflow the PL/SQL engine will raise a run time exception. But, calculations involving a binary_integer will not raise an exception even if there is an overflow.

Comment: Isn't true since oracle 11.2g. See example, which throws ORA-01426 error:
`declare
  limit binary_integer := 2147483647;
begin
  limit := limit + 1;
end;
/`