# Is there a reason why shouldn't I use the PL/SQL BINARY_INTEGER datatype from Oracle 10g onwards?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Friends,

This question is related to this  [one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412731/whats-the-difference-between-pls-integer-and-binary-integer)

Steven Feuerstein writes in his book, PL/SQL Programming, that he doesn't recommend using BINARY_INTEGER for new work unless it is going to be run on releases of Oracle prior to 7.3. (source 5th Edition page 238-239)

Given that PLS_INTEGER and BINARY_INTEGER are, from 10g R1, identical, why shouldn't it be used?

Comment: Because PLS_INTEGER is more future-proof than BINARY_INTEGER (i.e. any future development e.g. in performance might be done only to PLS_INTEGER) ? This, of course, is a highly speculative guess, but as I have learned recently many Oracle quirks are there because _historical reasons_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, The 11g language reference suggest both are equally valid.

see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/datatypes.htm#i10726