# Datatype of the PLSQL For loop counter

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, sqldatatypes

I understand that the index variable/counter for the `PL/SQL` For loop is defined implicitly by the loop construct

```
BEGIN
 FOR v_counter IN 1..5 LOOP
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('v_counter = '||v_counter);
 END LOOP;
END;
```

What is the datatype of this variable. Tempted to say `BINARY_INTEGER`  or `PLS_INTEGER` as this would allow for negative values of counters too , and both perform better as far as calculations are concerned.

Is this inference right ? Are there any other considerations ?

Comment: Don't think you can do that in pl/sql:   PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'DUMP' may be used inside a SQL statement

Comment: Ups, then do `select dump(v_counter)  into... From dual;`

Comment: @Wernfried: That only tells you it's "NUMBER" datatype ... it doesn't differentiate between PLS_INTEGER nor BINARY_INTEGER.  You have to understand, PLS_INTEGER and BINARY_INTEGER are PL/SQL data types .. not SQL data types. (try: `create table junk ( id  pls_integer );` ). So once you "convert" v_counter into SQL, it maps it to the nearest data type - NUMBER. and that's what you get. It doesn't help understand the PL/SQL datatype is within the PL/SQL block.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1536

States simply "integer".

Previous thread here:

[What's the difference between pls_integer and binary_integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412731/whats-the-difference-between-pls-integer-and-binary-integer)

Points out that binary_integer = pls_integer.

So it likely doesn't matter, since they (now) behave the same.