# PLSQL binary_integer data type

Tags: plsql

Why PLSQL Engine does not throw runtime exception when there is an overflow for binary_integer data type?

Can anyone explain?This was an interview question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between pls\_integer and binary\_integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412731/whats-the-difference-between-pls-integer-and-binary-integer)

Comment: could you provide some code?

Answer (score 1):

Actually `BINARY_INTEGER` (also known as `PLS_INTEGER`) raises an overflow exception.

Refer page 3-8 (bottom part) of below link.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519.pdf

> A calculation with two PLS_INTEGER values that overflows the
>   PLS_INTEGER range raises an overflow exception, even if you assign the
>   result to a NUMBER data type.

But there is a Subtype of `BINARY_INTEGER/PLS_INTEGER`, which is known as `SIMPLE_INTEGER`.

Now refer page 3-10 of same document

> If and only if all operands in an expression have the data type
>   SIMPLE_INTEGER, PL/SQL uses two's complement arithmetic and ignores
>   overflows.

So in this case when the positive max value is reached (+2147483647), the next number will begin with negative max value (-2147483648) and vice versa.

**ex:**

+2147483647 + 1 returns -2147483648

**and**

-2147483648 - 1 returns +2147483647

Because of this phenomenon, there won't be an overflow exception in case of `SIMPLE_INTEGER` type.

Answer (score 0):

The intereviewer was wrong.  it raises -1426 when there is an overflow.  I tried a very simple test:

```
declare xx pls_integer;
begin
    xx := 999999999999999;
end;
```

And even if it did not raise an error - that would be a bug in the language and if I may say so pretty stupid question for an interview!